# Properties of a smooth bijection

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

What are the basic facts about a map $F: M \to N$ between manifolds (without boundary, we might specify) which is a smooth bijection?

The map from $[0,1) \to S^1$ parameterizing the circle is a smooth bijection which is not a diffeomorphism, but of course here there is a boundary point.

Can we say anything if we add the hypothesis that $\dim{M}= \dim{N}$? Must such a map then be of constant rank, perhaps?

Comment: For $M=N=\Bbb R$, $x\mapsto x^3$ is not of constant rank.

Comment: If there is a smooth (continuous, even) bijection $F \colon M \to N$, then $M$ and $N$ have the same dimension, and $F$ is in fact a homeomorphism.